# How to get symbols on my shared lib with clang?

Tags: c, macos, linker, clang, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile [my lib](https://github.com/Luos-io/luos_engine) as a shared lib on Mac. You can find my attempt on [this PR](https://github.com/Luos-io/luos_engine/pull/474).

Here is the command line I'm using and the verbose result:

```bash
$ gcc -v -dynamiclib -fPIC -o .../luos_engine/.pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib .../luos_engine/.pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/libluos_engine.a
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 14.0.0 14.2 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o .../luos_engine/.pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib -L/usr/local/lib .../luos_engine/.pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/libluos_engine.a -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

The compilation seems to work as you can see, but when I try to get the symbols on the lib I don't have anything :

```bash
$ nm .pio/build/native_lib/libws_luos_engine.dylib
.pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib: no symbols
```

Why I don't have any symbols?

Comment: Thanks @DavidRanieri for your answer and typo fix .
I modified the command to be : 
```bash
gcc -v -dynamiclib -fPIC -install_name .../.pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib -o .../.pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib .../.pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/libluos_engine.a
```

But I still don't have any symbols using `nm`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean`-install_name .../.pio/build/native_lib`, but I think is not related with your problem.

Comment: I tried this one first, but didn't get any differences indeed.

Comment: Sorry then, I had problems with a shared library on macOS that was solved using `-install_name` (don't ask me why) , nice library by the way, congrats!

Comment: It's going to sound silly, but have you verified that there are symbols defined if you compile the code to a `.o` file?  Have you checked what happens without the complicated paths?  I've got the same `clang` in disguise, and I took one of my smaller library object files and compiled it to a `.dylib` using a simplified version of your command line and then ran `nm` on the resulting file and got the symbols I expected to see, both defined and undefined.  Hence the opening question…

Comment: Have you checked `libluos_engine.a` has symbols ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes I tested `libluos_engine.a` and it has symbols.

Comment: By following the suggestion of @JonathanLeffler I noticed that the binary is compiled for `x86_64` but my Mac is a `arm64`. The tool I use (Platformio) seems to add the `-arch x86_64` flag. I don't think this has any impact on this problem.
By compiling a simple `.o` with simple paths as `.dylib` with 
`clang -v -dynamiclib -fPIC -arch x86_64 -o .pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib .pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/luos_engine/stats.o`
I get the symbols.
The same line with `libluos_engine.a` gives me `no symbols` even if `libluos_engine.a` gets them.

Comment: Did you try `-fvisibility=default`?

Comment: @jayatubi I just tried `-fvisibility=default` and I don't get any symbols.

Comment: Then how about `nm -gU`?

Comment: @jayatubi `nm -gU` gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple explanation for this and a simple solution.

**The explanation.**

Your unsuccessful build command:

```
$ clang -v -dynamiclib -fPIC -o \
.../luos_engine/.pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib \
.../luos_engine/.pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/libluos_engine.a
```

is an example of:

```
$ clang ... -dynamiclib ... -o /path/to/libfoo.dylib /path/to/libfoo.a
```

I substitute `clang` where you had `gcc`, because your `gcc` is an alias for `clang`. The output is to be a dynamic library and and
the sole input is a static libary. You simply want to make a dynamic version of a static library, but no symbols appear in `libfoo.dylib`.

The contrasting successful build command which you present in a comment:

```
$ clang -v -dynamiclib -fPIC -arch x86_64 \
-o .pio/build/native_lib/libluos_engine.dylib \
.pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/luos_engine/stats.o
```

is an example of:

```
$ clang ... -dynamiclib ... -o /path/to/libfoo.dylib    /path/to/obj.o
```

i.e. the output is to be a dynamic library and and the sole input is an object file. You simply want to make
a dynamic library from an object file, and the symbols defined by that object file duly appear defined in
the dynamic library.

Your post describes the unsuccessful command as "the compilation". Likewise in your comment about the successful command
you describe it as "compiling". In both cases, no source files are input, no compiling is done: these are purely linkage commands<sup>1</sup>.
The compiler frontend delegates to the system static linker `ld`, as your verbose (`-v`) ouput from the unsuccessful command shows:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/[...cut...]/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library \
[...more arguments...]
```

Just as your `gcc` is an alias for `clang`, your `ld` is an alias for the MacOS system linker `ld64`.

The difference between success and failure is made by the difference between the way that a linker
consumes an object file explicitly input to the linkage and the default way in which it consumes a static libary:

- In case an explicit object file `obj.o` is input, the linker unconditionally links it into the outfile file (program or dynamic library),
  incorporating all new references to undefined symbols and all new symbol definitions from `obj.o`.
- In case a static library `libfoo.a` is input, it is an archive of object files `obj0.o`,...,`objN.o`. For each symbol `sym` already linked that is
  referenced but not defined, the linker inspects `obj0.o`,...,`objN.o` in turn to find the first that provides a definition of `sym`. If a definition
  is first provided by `objK.o`, then `objK` is copied out of the archive and linked as if were an explicitly named object file. The linker then
  restarts its consideration of `libfoo.a` from scratch and so continues until `libfoo.a` yields no new symbol definitions. Then the linker passes
  on from `libfoo.a` and never considers it again, unless it recurs later in the input sequence.

In this light consider what happens in the successful case:

```
$ clang ... -dynamiclib ... -o /path/to/libfoo.dylib    /path/to/obj.o
```

When the linker arrives at `obj.o`, that is the first and last input file. Nothing at all has so far been linked into `libfoo.dylib`, so there
are 0 undefined symbol references to resolve. Nevertheless, `obj.o` is unconditionally linked, bringing with it at least one symbol,
either defined or referenced but undefined. There are no more input files, so the linkage is done, and there is at least one symbol in `libfoo.dylib`.

Consider next what happens in the unsuccessful case:

```
$ clang ... -dynamiclib ... -o /path/to/libfoo.dylib /path/to/libfoo.a
```

When the linker arrives at `libfoo.a`, that is the first and last input file; nothing at all has so far been linked into `libfoo.dylib`, so there
are 0 undefined symbol references to resolve. Since `libfoo.a` is a static library, it will be searched only for definitions of unresolved references
already linked. There aren't any, so it is not searched. There are no more input files, so the linkage is done, and there are still no symbols in `libfoo.dylib`.

**The solution.**

Wanting to link all of the object files from a static library into a linked binary is a fairly common goal which may have good reasons. Linkers
provide options to override their default behaviour and accomplish this.

For the GNU/Linux linker, the relevant linker option is `--whole-archive`. When this option appears, it applies to all subsequent static libraries until the
countervailing option `--no-whole-archive` appears.

For the MacOS linker, the relevant linker options are `-force_load <somelib.a>` and `-all_load`. `_force_load` applies only the next argument, which should
resolve to the name of some static library. `-all_load` applies to all static libraries anywhere in the linkage.

These linker options are not recognised by either the GCC or the clang frontend. For both, you must indicate that a linker-specific option is to be
passed through to the linker by prefixing it with `-Wl,` ( think *with linker option,*). Thus if your linker is GNU/Linux `ld`, whether you are invoking it
via `gcc` or `clang`, you would replace:

```
/path/to/libfoo.a
```

with:

```
-Wl,--whole-archive /path/to/libfoo.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
# Do not neglect `--no-whole-archive` even the end of your commandline! 
# - there are going to be invisible default libraries following!
```

and if the linker is (really) MacOS `ld64`, then you would replace the same with:

```
-Wl,-force_load /path/to/libfoo.a
```

**Demo of the problem and the solution**

I do not have a MacOS Xcode environment like yours, but I have the MacOSX14.2 SDK installed on linux, plus:

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 16.0.6 (15)
```

which supports x86_64-apple-darwin targets, plus the LLVM linker driver:

```
$ lld --version
lld is a generic driver.
Invoke ld.lld (Unix), ld64.lld (macOS), lld-link (Windows), wasm-ld (WebAssembly)
```

supporting `ld64` emulation, plus linux-hosted `binutils` targeting MacOS `mach-o` binaries. These will do
the job.

A source file:

```
$ cat foo.c

int foo(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

Compile to `mach.o` object file:

```
$ clang -c -fPIC --target=x86_64-apple-darwin foo.c
$ file foo.o
foo.o: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 object, flags:<|SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS>
```

Make a static library:

```
$ ../mach-o-binutils/ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o
```

that contains just `foo.o` and whose symbol table includes only a definition of `foo`

```
$ ../mach-o-binutils/nm libfoo.a

foo.o:
0000000000000000 T _foo
```

Now make an absolutely minimal `libfoo.dylib` from `foo.o` itself:

```
$ clang -dynamiclib -o libfoo.dylib --target=x86_64-apple-darwin \
-fuse-ld=lld -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs --sysroot=../MacOSX14.2 foo.o
```

Here it is:

```
$ file libfoo.dylib 
libfoo.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 dynamically linked shared library, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS>
```

and here are its symbols:

```
$ ../mach-o-binutils/nm libfoo.dylib 
00000000000002d0 T _foo
```

`foo`, nothing but `foo`, and `foo` is defined (`T`).

Next do the same thing with `libfoo.a` in place of `foo.o`:

```
$ clang -dynamiclib -o libfoo.dylib --target=x86_64-apple-darwin \
-fuse-ld=lld -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs --sysroot=../MacOSX14.2 libfoo.a
```

No complaints from that, but:

```
$ ../mach-o-binutils/nm libfoo.dylib 
../mach-o-binutils/nm: libfoo.dylib: no symbols
```

which is the right and proper outcome of that linkage, though not the desired one. If we `-force_load libfoo.a`:

```
$ clang -dynamiclib -o libfoo.dylib --target=x86_64-apple-darwin \
-fuse-ld=lld -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs --sysroot=../MacOSX14.2 -Wl,-force_load libfoo.a
```

we get the desired outcome:

```
$ ../mach-o-binutils/nm libfoo.dylib 
00000000000002d0 T _foo
```

---

1. Relatedly, your own linkage commands, both unsuccessful and successful, specify `-fPIC`. This is a *compiler* option, directing the compiler to emit
   position independent object code capable of being linked in a dynamic library, and that must have already been done, or not, at linktime.
   If you pass `-fPIC` to a `gcc` or `clang` linkage command it is innocuous and ignored. So if the object files in your `.pio/build/native_lib/libdf9/libluos_engine.a`
   static library were not compiled `-fPIC`, linking any or all of them into a dynamic library with `-fPIC` would do nothing about that and a linkage relocation error
   would result. They probably have been so compiled. For most of the past decade most packaged builds of GCC and Clang
   have compiled `-fPIC` by default and you would need to specify `-fno-pic` to disable it; but specifying `-fPIC` where it is significant remains good
   careful form.